# reattaching to screen daemon makes backspace kill whole line

Tags: gnu-screen

As part of my startup script to set up my desktop, I initialize a screen with several windows. I do this by starting a daemon and sending it `-X screen` and `-X stuff` commands, finally reattaching with `-r`.

Unfortunately, the "create daemon and reattach" method makes all the windows I created turn backspace into a "kill whole line" action. If I create new windows within screen with `C-c c`, the new windows do not have this behavior. Is this a screen bug, or can I do something special to fix this behavior? I'm using xfce4 and ubuntu 12.10 if that matters

Repro with the following:

```
screen -S -dm
screen -r
```

Type several characters and press backspace.

Comment: One simplification is possible: use `$'ff\015'` to embed the carriage return in place of the call to `echo`.

Comment: Type `stty` or, if necessary, `stty -a` and see what character `kill` is set to (`^H`, is backspace, `^?` is delete). Then type control-V, backspace at a shell prompt to see what key is sent by the backspace key. I suspect the backspace key is sending the delete character. From there, you can either change your tty settings so Delete doesn't clear the whole line, *or* you can track down why backspace is sending Delete rather than Backspace (probably a setting in `xfce4-terminal`).

Comment: kill is still set to ^H, and delete still kills a single following character.

Comment: It's sufficient to simply reattach to screen after starting it with -dm to get this backspace behavior. Still no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm having the exact same problem as you, as your repro steps didn't work for me, but I did have the same bad behavior in `screen` (backspace killing the whole line), and managed to fix it.

For me, somehow I repeatedly get into a state where the output of `stty` is this:

```
$ stty
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: echoe echok echoke echoctl
iflags: -ixany -imaxbel ignpar
oflags: tab3
cflags: cs8 -parenb -hupcl clocal
eol     eol2    erase2  kill    min     
^@      ^@      ^@      ^H      0
```

Two things to note here:

1. There is no `erase`, only `erase2`
2. `kill` is mapped to `^H`

#2 explains my issue, though #1 needs fixing, too.
Normally, `^U` is "kill line", but here it is `^H` instead.

If I type `Ctrl-V, <backspace>`, my terminal outputs `^H`. So due to that mapping above, that causes the `kill` (kill line) to happen.

This fixed it for me:

```
$ stty kill ^U
# now, backspace outputs a literal ^H to the screen, so...
$ stty erase ^H
```

Note that in order to input the `^U` and `^H`, you have to use the literal control characters. I do this on my terminal with
<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-U</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
, respectively.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around to this issue.

```
screen -r {session_name} -p 0 -X stuff "stty $(stty -g)"
screen -r {session_name} -p 0 -X stuff $'\n'
screen -r {session_name} -p 0 -X width $COLUMNS $LINES
screen -r {session_name} -p 0 -X stuff $'clear\n'
```

This takes the current tty settings and "stuffs" them into the screen session on Window 0, the default window that screen create on first launch. Then it "stuff" a newline to simulate pressing enter.

The next two lines are just to tell screen that initial columns and lines should match the calling terminal's columns and lines, then it clears the session's screen so that when you attach to the screen session your prompt will be at the top left.  I was having issues of when attaching to the screen session the prompt would be in the middle of the terminal.  A minor annoyance, but I wanted it gone.

**NOTE:** If you call the last two lines from within a script, those environment variables are not set.  You will need to replace with *$(tput cols)* and *$(tput lines)*